Sanity.io npm deploy command causes a memory leak when run in a Digital Ocean Droplet
I have a sanity.io project, and when I run npx sanity deploy locally it gets deployed smoothely. However, every time I do it from a Digital Ocean droplet, the command takes forever to finish and memory and cpu keep rising until the whole system crashes. It's the exact same code that comes bundled with Sanity's default starter project, and it's the same code that seems to deploys fine locally, so I'm not sure what could be causing it. Any thoughts?

I suggest you move away from hosted to serverless/static configuration. It will make your life so much easier.
Sanity CMS application is just a React app decoupled from the database so you can "host" it on the edge. I'm using Cloudflare Pages & Workers but there are other options. You won't ever worry about VPS, OS updates, Node updates, security, scalability, and all that is history.
For the front-end, if it's a website I love 11ty SSG (again, there are many options here), and if it's a web app I'm using SvelteKit, all on Cloudflare Pages. No servers, no headaches.
Cheers.
